# How do I send line break in a Ruby email?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, actionmailer

I'm using `\n` and they are showing up as literal `\n`

```
class TestMailer < ActionMailer::Base 

  def simple_mail(to, subject, body)
    mail(:to => to, :subject => subject, :body => body)
  end

end

TestMailer.simple_mail('my@email.com', 'subject', 'hi\n there').deliver
```

I see the literal `\n` in my inbox.

Answer (score 3):

Single quotes only allow you to escape ' and \ within a string. For example

```
puts 'That\'s all folks'
puts 'This is a single backslash \\'
```

Whereas double quotes allow you to escape many more escape sequences. They also allow you to embed variables inside of a string literal using [interpolation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Strings#Interpolation).

Some of the escape sequences available for double quotes include:

- \" – double quote
- \ – single backslash
- \a – bell/alert
- \b – backspace
- \r – carriage return
- \n – newline
- \s – space
- \t – tab

Comment: I'll try putting everything in double quotes. Right now I get the text from an inbound e-mail, then I'm parsing that. I'll try reading from the inbound e-mail params, putting into double quotes, and then parsing eg #{inbound_message_body}

Comment: Another common issue that I've found with ActionMailer and escaped output often has to do with rendering string literals having html tags when the string literal does not have its SafeBuffer flag set to true. This does not appear to be the case in this situation, but another aspect of working with string literals in views worth being aware of. Let me know if you need me to elaborate on that.

Comment: I'm not familiar with SafeBuffer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `"hi\n there"` instead of `'hi\n there'`. Still better, use `"hi#$/ there"`.

Comment: I'm getting \ns when I respond to a message, then forwarding that message to another account.